# wep page to rtmp (browser to rtmp )

Tags: node.js, browser, rtmp

I wanted to record a webpage with all operations happening inside it using node for eg. we have obs open source tool where we can add a browser scene to capture whatever is going on the webpage. suggest something that captures every part of that page that can contain audio or video elements with some textual or animated content. i only wanted to pass the URL, it will be redirected to capturing and embedding in rtmp stream.

NOTE: USE HEADLESS BROWSER FOR ANY OPERATION

I got a method but didn't get successful in it as I tried using Puppeteer for capturing the screenshot and fetching all the audio elements using node-fetch and after that merging the whole stream with FFmpeg.